# Notepad++ - Delete String Within Bookmarked Lines

Tags: notepad++

Bookmarked Lines:

```
(All Bookmarked Lines Have This), (This Is Different Each Line), (I Want To Delete This)
```

I am trying to delete the string "(I Want To Delete This)" for just the bookmarked lines.

Real Bookmarked Lines:

```
plugin command("plugin.dll", "local dictionary add", "usertemp", $list item(%details, 2), "Local")
plugin command("plugin.dll", "local dictionary add", "passtemp", $list item(%details, 3), "Local")
```

Need to get them to:

```
plugin command("plugin.dll", "local dictionary add", "usertemp", $list item(%details, 2))
plugin command("plugin.dll", "local dictionary add", "passtemp", $list item(%details, 3))
```

Comment: Should be possible with a regex search and replace. It would be easier to help if you posted a couple of lines of real data.

Comment: So are you willing to tell us what the heck is _"bookmarked"_ lines ?

Comment: @Lallen - I made the edit

Comment: Wel you've just changed the entire question! All you need to do here is to replace `, "Local")` with `)`. I will remove my answer below in that case.

Comment: No, there is other code in the file with that string in it. It needs to be done only on the bookmarke lines. However, I think your original answer did solve it using /1

Answer (score 0):

Search and Replace, Search mode regex.

Find what:`,[^,]*?\)$`

Replace with: `\)`

run Replace all once

If (I want to delete this) always is `, "Local"` you could use Find what: `, "Local"\)$` instead. my example above matches and removes the last "argument" from each parenthesis with multiple arguments